# Google Analytics is not showing tables while getting data to Power BI

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to query my Google Analytics data with Power Bi desktop. I pick the connector, add my google login details and I can see the Account and Property but I am unable to see the data tables and am therefore unable to connect to view / chart the GA data. I have administrator role in the company I am trying to connect. This company also connects for getting GA to Firebase.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I have the latest 64bit version of Power Bi desktop (and have reinstalled)

Thanks in advance

I tried to connect according to Microsoft Power BI descriptions.

I have tried another company I have access too and got tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are trying to connect to a GA4 property. The other company works because they are using UA. Apparently there's no solution yet, other than using an external connector.